# Faster Merge Sort with Multithreading

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, sorting, merge

My task is instead of giving a huge array to Arrays.sort() which only uses one thread, rather slice a big array into smaller arrays, and each thread sorts an array, then merge all the little arrays into a big one.

I mesured the time each section takes and the join() takes the longest time but i have to wait for every thread to finish.

I also tried merging after a join() since it finished sorting that array but it takes even longer.

Is there any way to make it more faster?

Merging:

```
/* Create new sorted array by merging 2 smaller sorted arrays */
private static int[] merge(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    // TODO: merge sorted arrays 'arr1' and 'arr2'

    int[] mergedArray = new int[arr1.length + arr2.length];

    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    while (i < arr1.length && j < arr2.length) {
        if (arr1[i] < arr2[j]) {
            mergedArray[k] = arr1[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            mergedArray[k] = arr2[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    while (i < arr1.length) {
        mergedArray[k] = arr1[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    while (j < arr2.length) {
        mergedArray[k] = arr2[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }

    return mergedArray;
}
```

Slicing:

```
/* Creates an array of arrays by slicing a bigger array into smaller chunks */
private static int[][] slice(int[] arr, int k) {
    //TODO: cut 'arr' into 'k' smaller arrays

   
    int temp = 0;
    final int[][] copyArray = new int[k][];
    int x = (int) Math.ceil((double)arr.length / (double)k);  // chunk size
    int len = arr.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < len - x + 1; i += x)
        copyArray[temp++] = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, i, i + x);

    if (len % x != 0)
        copyArray[temp++] = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, len - len % x, len);

    return copyArray;
}
```

Main:

```
public static int[] sort(int[] array) {

    /* Initialize variables */
    // TODO: check available processors and create necessary variables
    int dbProcessor = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    int[][] slicedArray;
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[dbProcessor];

    /* Turn initial array into array of smaller arrays */
    // TODO: use 'slice()' method to cut 'array' into smaller bits

    slicedArray = slice(array, dbProcessor);

    /* parralelized sort on the smaller arrays */
    // TODO: use multiple threads to sort smaller arrays (Arrays.sort())

    int[][] finalSlicedArray = slicedArray;
    int size = finalSlicedArray.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < size ; ++i) {
        int finalI = i;
        if (finalSlicedArray[finalI] == null) {
            break;
        }
        threads[i] = new Thread(() -> {
           // counter++;
            Arrays.sort(finalSlicedArray[finalI]);
        });
        threads[i].start();
    }

    for (Thread thread : threads) {
        try {
            if (thread == null) {
                break;
            }
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /* Merge sorted smaller arrays into a singular larger one */
    // TODO: merge into one big array using 'merge()' multiple times
    //       create an empty array called 'sorted' and in a for cycle use
    //       'merge(sorted, arr2d[i])' where arr2d is an array of sorted arrays

    int[] sorted = new int[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (finalSlicedArray[i] == null) {
            break;
        }
        sorted = merge(sorted, finalSlicedArray[i]);
    }

    return sorted;
}
```

Comment: Just FYI I've tried doing something like this with a quicksort and my conclusion was that a multithreaded sort takes longer for one million elements.  Basically  starting the threads eats up any time savings.  I'd have to keep threads around waiting for a sort task, and that consumes memory and leaves some heavyweight objects unable to be GC'd.  Unless you're sorting around 10 million elements or more regularly, multithreading might not be worth it.

Comment: Why not just use [Arrays.parallelSort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#parallelSort-T:A-), which will honestly be a lot better than anything you can handwrite?

Comment: @markspace I wouldn't use multi threading for sorting but my teacher gave us this task and i got a little worried that it takes way more time than if i just used the Arrays.sort() in one big array, and even our desciption of the task says it should take less time so i got a little worried

Comment: @LouisWasserman i am learining multi threading at school now, and the teacher gave us this task and i have no clue how to improve the speed. And thanks for the link, i will check it out!

Comment: `our desciption of the task says it should take less time` This certainly could be baloney.  I'd bring your assignment to your instructor and ask for advice, they may be unaware of some of the difficulty involved.  Java's `Arrays.sort()` is a very very optimized method, one some of the best people working for Oracle could produce.  I think it's going to be hard to beat it.  (I'm not joking about "best people" either, I watched them do this on the dev list a few years back and it was a non-trivial exercise getting `sort()` working as fast as possible.)